# Stripe - Pay order error : Cannot charge a customer that has no active card

Tags: php, stripe-payments, card

I am using Stripe's API to pay for orders.

My plan is generally the following:

1. Creation of the payment form with Stripe Elements
2. Card authentication (3d secure security SCA) through the use of a PaymentIntent then the creation of a PaymentMethod.
3. Creation of the Customer object, to which I attach the payment method, and which I define as default

```php
$customer = $this->stripeConnector->updateCustomer($customer->id, [
     'invoice_settings' => [
          'default_payment_method' => $paymentMethod->id,
        ],
   ]);
```

4. Creation of the subscription, or of a single payment.

Normally it works fine.

But not for the **Order**.
I create **Order Object** following the documentation : https://stripe.com/docs/api/orders/create with the orders items and the associated Customer

And I pay it following the following documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api/orders/pay

So, just by passing the **Order** **id** (because the customer is already associated to the order).

But I've the following error : **Cannot charge a customer that has no active card**

Why ? And how can I 'activate' the customer card ?

This is an example of a Customer data that I have :

```json
{
  "id": "cus_JocNLLNhqHuOD6",
  "object": "customer",
  "address": {
    "city": "paris",
    "country": "FR",
    "line1": "5 rue pompidou",
    "line2": null,
    "postal_code": "75000",
    "state": null
  },
  "balance": 0,
  "created": 1625758082,
  "currency": null,
  "default_source": null,
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "email": "admin@mail.fr",
  "invoice_prefix": "D46F6A15",
  "invoice_settings": {
    "custom_fields": null,
    "default_payment_method": "pm_1JAz8uGgCQgXBLKX2hoxLQHr",
    "footer": null
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "name": "admin admin",
  "next_invoice_sequence": 1,
  "phone": null,
  "preferred_locales": [
    "fr"
  ],
  "shipping": null,
  "tax_exempt": "none"
}
```

And my PaymentMethod response :

```json
{
  "id": "pm_1JAz8uGgCQgXBLKX2hoxLQHr",
  "object": "payment_method",
  "billing_details": {
    "address": {
      "city": null,
      "country": null,
      "line1": null,
      "line2": null,
      "postal_code": null,
      "state": null
    },
    "email": null,
    "name": "qsvsf",
    "phone": null
  },
  "card": {
    "brand": "visa",
    "checks": {
      "address_line1_check": null,
      "address_postal_code_check": null,
      "cvc_check": "pass"
    },
    "country": "US",
    "exp_month": 5,
    "exp_year": 2025,
    "fingerprint": "oV7uH07M2JEz7jQm",
    "funding": "credit",
    "generated_from": null,
    "last4": "4242",
    "networks": {
      "available": [
        "visa"
      ],
      "preferred": null
    },
    "three_d_secure_usage": {
      "supported": true
    },
    "wallet": null
  },
  "created": 1625758080,
  "customer": "cus_JocNLLNhqHuOD6",
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "type": "card"
}
```

Looking at the doc on the payment of an Order object, I wonder if I should instead use the 'source' option and therefore use a Source object instead of a PaymentMethod. But the problem is, the Source Object is deprecated in favor of the PaymentMethod to favor 3d secure, so I have to use it.

Comment: When you create the payment method, what is its resulting type attribute? https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-type

Comment: This is 'card' type attribute. I updated my first post with PaymentMethod response

Comment: Hmmm. Did you double check that when you're creating and paying for the order you're also hitting the test/sandbox environment?

Comment: Yes yes, it uses the test environment well, no worries about that.

Besides, if I switch using the Source object to feed a card, rather than a PaymentMethod, it works, but I no longer have to use the Source Object since it is deprecated and does not support authentication SCA 3d secure. We are obliged to go through the PaymentMethod. I don't know if there is an extra option to put somewhere, it's very weird

Comment: added a detailed answer, you're using Orders which is a deprecated API and only supports `sources` param on a Customer and does not support PaymentMethods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orders is a long deprecated Stripe API, so I would recommend moving away from it, to PaymentIntents or one-off Invoices.

Since it is a legacy API, it only works with Cards/Sources and not PaymentMethods.

Right now your integration is attaching a PaymentMethod to your Customer.

Orders doesn't look for your Customer's PaymentMethods but instead it looks under the `sources:` param on your Customer.

Orders also don't support SCA, so if a payment requires authentication, that would just surface as a decline and not give you the authentication life-cycle functionality that PaymentIntents give you.

That is why it works as you said, when you save a "Source" object under the Customer's `source:`.

The right approach would be to move away from using deprecated Card/Source objects and the Orders API, and integrate PaymentMethods (which you already have integrated) and PaymentIntents or Invoices or CheckoutSessions.

Comment: Really ? So bad ... but suddenly, can I still use Product objects associated with Sku objects?

I mean, if I create a Product Object "T shirt", and several Sku objects associated with that product, with different colors and sizes, stocks, could I then use these skus with Invoice, PaymentMethod, or PaymentIntent, as a 'order item?

Comment: SKUs aren't recommended but Prices are recommended instead, you can create Prices off Products. Then you can create an InvoiceItem on a Customer, using that Price and send send the Invoice via email to the Customer. The "Hosted Invoice Page" supports SCA. Or create a CheckoutSession for that Customer (as a payment page on your website), which also supports SCA.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it is no longer up to Stripe to manage stocks, and product items, but up to us to do everything in our own database, and at the time of payment, to calculate everything by ourselves ?

Comment: yes that is correct, since Orders is deprecated, you would handle inventory/stock/etc on your application side